# ¿Cómo cargar datos a un arreglo de una clase en c++?

Tags: c++

Tengo un archivo .txt llamado laboratorios, el cual tiene cuatro columnas de datos; tengo una clase .h tambien llamada laboratorio.h que tiene metodos de acceso y modificacion y tengo un main (c++) que tiene un arreglo laboratorios[n].

Como puedo cargar los datos del .txt al arreglo del main?

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda que es importante agregar lo que trataste por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: No dejó el código que le está andando mal (requisito obligatorio).

Answer (score 0):

Para leer los datos de un archivo txt puedes sobrecargar el operador de inserción `operator>>` en tu clase laboratorio.

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &input, Laboratorio &lab);
```

Nótese que el parámetro `Laboratorio` es una referencia sin el calificador `const` porque el propósito de esto es asignar los valores leídos del archivo a los atributos de la clase, entonces suponiendo que dicha clase tiene cuatro atributos, el cuerpo de la función tiene que ser así:

```
class Laboratorio{
    std::string str1_{};
    std::string str2_{};
    int num1_{};
    float num2_{};

    // sobrecarga del operador >>
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &input, Laboratorio &lab){
        input >> lab.str1_ >> lab.str2_ >> lab.num1_ >> lab.num2_;
        return input;
    }
public:
    Laboratorio() = default;

    void imprimir() const{
        std::cout<<"str 1: "<<str1_<<'\n';
        std::cout<<"str 2: "<<str2_<<'\n';
        std::cout<<"num 1: "<<num1_<<'\n';
        std::cout<<"num 2: "<<num2_<<'\n';
    }
};
```

Y la manera en que la función que sobrecarga el operador puede acceder a los atributos de la clase es poniendo delante de la función el calificador `friend`.

Ahora a modo de ejemplo para leer un archivo txt de nombre datos.txt con un solo registro como el siguiente:

> **Ahumada Cerrillos 100 20.045**

Se tiene que instanciar un objeto de la clase `std::ifstream` pasándole al constructor el nombre de nuestro archivo, luego instanciar el objeto de la clase `Laboratorio` que es el que recibirá los datos para finalmente leerlos llamando nuestra sobrecarga del operador `>>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // para std::ifstream

int main(){
    std::ifstream archivo("datos.txt");
    Laboratorio lab;

    archivo >> lab;

    lab.imprimir();

    return 0;
}
```

Por último para leer un archivo txt que contiene más de un registro conviene que cada registro esté separado por un salto de línea incluso poner un salto de línea al final del último registro para manipular los datos con facilidad:

Se tiene un archivo txt de nombre datos.txt con el siguiente contenido:

> **Ahumada Cerrillos 100 20.045**
>
> **Cruz Verde 500 10.3**
>
> **Soto Mayor 34 5.5**
>
> **Juan Lopez 123 3.21**
>
> **Marta Carvajal 3020 7.006**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // para std::ifstream

int main(){
    std::ifstream archivo("datos.txt");
    Laboratorio laboratorios[5], inputLab;
    int i = 0;

    archivo >> inputLab;

    while(!archivo.eof()){
        laboratorios[i++] = inputLab;
        archivo >> inputLab;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        laboratorios[i].imprimir();
        std::cout<<'\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

El método `eof` del objeto archivo le indica al ciclo while si hay o no más registros que leer del archivo, cuando haya llegado al final del archivo significa que no hay más registros habiendo terminado de leer todo y se sale del ciclo while, luego en el ciclo for se muestra que el array de tipo laboratorio se ha llenado con los datos del archivo.